# Can I convert soft returns into hard returns in a MS Word document using Python?

Tags: python, ms-word

I now have a MS Word document containing soft returns. I'd want to convert all the soft returns into hard returns. Is Python capable of doing that? I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need python to do that. MS Word provides a way to do just that. Use **Find and Replace**. Here's how:

1. Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Find and Replace** window.
2. Click on **More** button to bring up more Search Options.
3. Place the cursor in the **Find what** box, and select **Manual Line Break** from the Special drop-down list. Look at the image below.

[image: find manual line-break]

4. Place the cursor in the **Replace with** box, and select **Paragraph Mark** from the Special drop-down list. Refer to the image below.

[image: replace with paragraph mark]

5. Click Replace All.

I would like to impart due credit to the author of [this post](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/658-replace-soft-returns-with-hard-returns.html#a1) from where I collected this. I only did slight modifications :)

Visit the link, it contains two other procedures to do this job!

Comment: I understand. But I have to use Python because I'm required to do so for a business program. I appreciate your help and patience anyway.

Comment: @joewong Then you should take a look at christutty's answer. I haven't used that package myself though. Also if you could tell us *why* you need that, may be some more elegant work-arounds would be possible.

Comment: I think using the Word dialog you want to replace with **Paragraph Character** instead of **Paragraph Mark** if actually having the line break is desired. That has been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) package looks like a good place to start.